# Laravel getting 404 error when creating new route

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

it appears that when I created a new route, I receive the 404 error when trying to access the url, which is funny,. because all of my other routes are working just fine.

My web.php looks like so:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::post('follow/{user}', 'FollowsController@store');

Route::get('/acasa', 'HomeController@index')->name('acasa');
Route::get('/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profil');
Route::get('/profil/{user}/edit', 'ProfilesController@edit')->name('editareprofil');
Route::patch('/profil/{user}', 'ProfilesController@update')->name('updateprofil');

Route::get('/alerte', 'PaginaAlerte@index')->name('alerte');
Route::get('/alerte/url/{user}', 'UrlsController@index')->name('editurl');
Route::post('/alerte/url/{user}', 'UrlsController@store')->name('updateurl');
Route::get('/alerte/url/{del_id}/delete','UrlsController@destroy')->name('deleteurl');
```

The one that is NOT working when I am visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000/alerte is:

```
Route::get('/alerte', 'PaginaAlerte@index')->name('alerte');
```

The controller looks like so:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class PaginaAlerte extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index(User $user)
    {
        return view('alerte');
    }
}
```

I am banging my head around as I cannot see which is the problem. It is not a live website yet, I am just developing on my Windows 10 pc using WAMP.

Comment: Can you move your `/alerte` route before `/{username}` one? It seems they are conflicting with each other

Comment: That one worked alexey, thank you very much. I am new to laravel and these things are really confusing.

Comment: your welcome, @FBK ) For sure routing of the Laravel will confuse at the first time, but then you'll like it :) I'll add a bit more explained answer, so maybe it could help to someone else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moved my comment to a little bit explained answer.

So, in your route collection, you have two conflicting routes

```php
Route::get('/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profil');
```

and

```php
Route::get('/alerte', 'PaginaAlerte@index')->name('alerte');
```

Imagine that Laravel is reading all routings from top to bottom and it stops to reading next one after the first match.

In your case, Laravel is thinking that `alerte` is a username and going to the `ProfilesController@index` controller. Then it tries to find a user with `alerte` username and returning 404 because for now, you don't have a user with this username.

So to fix 404 error and handle `/alerte` route, you just need to move the corresponding route before `/{username}` one.

But here is the dilemma that you got now. What if you will have a user with `alerte` username? In this case, the user can't see his profile page because now `alerte` is handling by another route.

And I'm suggesting to use a bit more friendly URL structure for your project. Like `/user/{username}` to handle some actions with users and still use `/alerte` to handle alert routes.

Comment: wow thank you this finally helped me solve this, wow. lol

Answer (score 1):

The following route catches the url `/alerte` as well

```
Route::get('/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profil');
```

Since this one is specified before

```
Route::get('/alerte', 'PaginaAlerte@index')->name('alerte');
```

The `/alerte` will go the the `ProfilesController` instead.

To fix this change the order of the url definitions or change either of the urls to have nesting e.g. `/alerte/home` or `/user/{user}`

Comment: Moving the /alerte route before /{user} did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well.
Maybe this is too late, but I have all week dealing with this problem.
I made my own custom.php file and add it in the routes path of my Laravel project, and none of the routes were working at all.

This is how I solved it:

- You must remember to edit the `RouteServiceProvider.php` file located in `app\Providers` path. In the `map()` function, you must add your .php file. **That should work fine!**

To avoid unexpected behaviors, **map your custom routes first**. Some Laravel based systems can "stop" processing routes if no one of the expected routes rules were satisfied. I face that problem, and was driving me crazy!

Comment: Not sure what is meant by:
> In the map() function, you must add your .php file. That should work fine!
Having the same problem, do you have example code of what you did to resolve this?

Comment: Hi @GemmaDLou. RouteServiceProvider is a subclass of ServiceProvider. There is a defined method called map(), where you have to register the routes files (web.php, api.php and so on). So, you can create your own file for defining your routes and must be included in this service provider file. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I would wish suggest to you declare your URL without the "/", like your first "post" route, because sometimes, I have been got this kind of errors (404).

So, my first recomendation is change the declaration of the route. After that, you should test your middleware, try without the construct, and try again.

Good luck!